# Elementor change section image on button hover on column

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I am new to elemetor and just wanted to explore the plugin. I have seen the website of [Hongkong University](https://www.hku.hk/) and there is a part there where if a user hovers over the text,  the background image would change. The change depends on the text being hovered. I wanted to recreate this under elementor but can't figure how.

I tried adding a custom id to the section and button (via elementor), then adding custom CSS codes in WordPress. Unfortunately, I was unsuccessful. If this is not possible using elementor, may I know if there is a plugin that has the same function? Thank you.

Comment: That part uses JavaScript. https://nimb.ws/XHPBnk You need to change the active class using JavaScript and display the background-image using CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked the website you have mentioned above. You can make it using Elementor and some custom coding. Please check this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ja8HuMZ0vR4) which will help you to understand how you can make the same as per your requirement. You need to just change it as background image and hover on text selector.

You can also check [this tutorial](https://element.how/elementor-background-change-hover/) to get another idea. Code snippets are also added there